# while deploying existing Business network Getting Sysntax Error

Tags: hyperledger-composer

While deploying existing business network getting following error:-

> > SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Answer (score 0):

There is not very much information in your question, but I would guess that you have made changes to your `logic.js` script and have a syntax error in it!